# XSLT: Foreach iterates for each item, but displays the value of the first item?

Tags: xslt, foreach

I have a item list and for each item I want to make it an url.

List:

```
 <root>
   <tags>
     <tag>open source</tag>
     <tag>open</tag>
     <tag>advertisement</tag>
     <tag>ad</tag>
   </tags>
 </root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <div class="tags">
      <xsl:for-each select="/post/tags/tag">
          <a href="#">
            <xsl:value-of select="//tag"/>
          </a>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Output:

```
  <div class="tags"> 
    <a href="#">open source</a> 
    <a href="#">open source</a> 
    <a href="#">open source</a> 
    <a href="#">open source</a> 
  </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing with the value-of expression is selecting all of the tag nodes in the xml document:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//tag"/>
```

The effect of that is that only the first selected node will be used for the value.

You can use the following instead:

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

Where select="." will select the current node from the for-each.

Answer (score 5):

A more XSLT way of doing the correct thing is add a "tag" template and modify your original:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <div class="tags">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tag" />
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag">
      <a href="#">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </a>
</xsl:template>
```